# How to get the Messaging-Control?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I use the same control as in SMS, WhatsApp or any other chat program?

[image: Screenshot of SMS]

Comment: If you don't want to rely on 3rd party controls, check out this [IMPLEMENTING A WINDOWS PHONE 7 CONVERSATION VIEW](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/07/15/a-wp7-conversation-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know [Conversation View](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/conversation-view.aspx) but it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Coding4Fun has it! It's called ChatBubble - find more info on how to use it [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-coding4fun-chatbubble).

Find the library on Nuget or [here](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/)